# How to upload image in dynamic rows system config?

Tags: magento2, file-upload, dynamic-rows

I need to add a image field in my dynamic rows system config

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I made an image uploader in a dynamic array
https://github.com/mavlikhanov/image_dymanic_config/

In short, add in system.xml backend_model field:

```
    <section id="swatch" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Image Array Swatch</label>
        <tab>mr</tab>
        <resource>Mr_ImageDynamicConfig::config</resource>
        <group id="image_serializer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <field id="image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Image</label>
                <frontend_model>Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\ImageFields</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
                <upload_dir>var/uploads/swatch/image_serializer</upload_dir>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
```

Next step, create Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized class

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Model\Config\ImageConfig $imageConfig,
    \Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Model\ImageUploaderFactory $imageUploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = [],
    Json $serializer = null
) {
    $this->imageUploaderFactory = $imageUploaderFactory;
    $this->imageConfig = $imageConfig;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $config,
        $cacheTypeList,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data,
        $serializer
    );
}

public function beforeSave(): ArraySerialized
{
    $value = $this->getValue();
    $value = $this->mapRows($value);
    $this->setValue($value);
    return parent::beforeSave();
}

private function mapRows(array $rows): array
{
    $iconUploader = $this->imageUploaderFactory->create([
        'path' => $this->getPath(),
        'uploadDir' => $this->getUploadDir(),
    ]);
    $uploadedFiles = $iconUploader->upload();
    $swatches = $this->imageConfig->getSwatches();
    foreach ($rows as $id => $data) {
        if (isset($uploadedFiles[$id])) {
            $rows[$id][ImageFields::IMAGE_FIELD] = $uploadedFiles[$id];
            continue;
        }
        if (!isset($swatches[$id])) {
            unset($swatches[$id]);
        } else {
            $rows[$id] = $this->matchRow($data, $swatches[$id]);
        }
    }
    return $rows;
}

private function matchRow(array $row, array $configTabIcon): array
{
    foreach ($row as $fieldName => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && $fieldName == ImageFields::IMAGE_FIELD) {
            $row[ImageFields::IMAGE_FIELD] = $configTabIcon[ImageFields::IMAGE_FIELD];
        }
    }
    return $row;
}

private function getUploadDir(): string
{
    $fieldConfig = $this->getFieldConfig();

    if (!array_key_exists('upload_dir', $fieldConfig)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('The base directory to upload file is not specified.')
        );
    }

    if (is_array($fieldConfig['upload_dir'])) {
        $uploadDir = $fieldConfig['upload_dir']['value'];
        if (array_key_exists('scope_info', $fieldConfig['upload_dir'])
            && $fieldConfig['upload_dir']['scope_info']
        ) {
            $uploadDir = $this->_appendScopeInfo($uploadDir);
        }

        if (array_key_exists('config', $fieldConfig['upload_dir'])) {
            $uploadDir = $this->getUploadDirPath($uploadDir);
        }
    } else {
        $uploadDir = (string)$fieldConfig['upload_dir'];
    }

    return $uploadDir;
}
```

Method 'mapRows' upload image and merge data with config rows

Displaying image:
1)
in frontend_model add Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\ImageFields

```
    const IMAGE_FIELD = 'image';
const NAME_FIELD = 'name';
private $imageRenderer;

protected function _prepareToRender()
{
    $this->addColumn(
        self::IMAGE_FIELD,
        [
            'label' => __('Image'),
            'renderer' => $this->getImageRenderer()
        ]
    );

    $this->addColumn(
        self::NAME_FIELD,
        [
            'label' => __('Name'),
        ]
    );

    $this->_addAfter       = false;
    $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
}

private function getImageRenderer()
{
    if (!$this->imageRenderer) {
        $this->imageRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\ImageColumn::class,
            '',
            ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
        );
    }
    return $this->imageRenderer;
}
```

2)\Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\ImageColumn

```
public function setInputName(string $value)
{
    return $this->setName($value);
}

public function setInputId(string $value)
{
    return $this->setId($value);
}

protected function _toHtml(): string
{
    $imageButton = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock(ImageButton::class)
        ->setData('id', $this->getId())
        ->setData('name', $this->getName());
    return $imageButton->toHtml();
}
```

Method _toHtml render block \Mr\ImageDynamicConfig\Block\Adminhtml\ImageButton and return html with file upload button and uploaded image

P.S. this is my first answer don’t judge strictly, please

Comment: The solution is not functioning properly in the admin panel. We are unable to see the tab, and there is no error log available for this issue.